# Crashlytics confusing log

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I got this very confusing crash log from crashlytics and I couldn't understand what's causing the crash of my app, can anyone help me to translate this?

```
   #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Dev                            0x10005e3a0 specialized CurrentGameViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (CurrentGameViewController.swift)
1  Dev                            0x100057ce4 @objc CurrentGameViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (CurrentGameViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x18d5843d4 <redacted> + 716
3  UIKit                          0x18d584604 <redacted> + 80
4  UIKit                          0x18d571bac <redacted> + 2304
5  UIKit                          0x18d5722dc <redacted> + 4144
6  UIKit                          0x18d5722dc <redacted> + 4144
7  UIKit                          0x18d5722dc <redacted> + 4144
8  UIKit                          0x18d589668 <redacted> + 116
9  UIKit                          0x18d325b14 <redacted> + 176
10 UIKit                          0x18d23e54c <redacted> + 1196
11 QuartzCore                     0x18a70640c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
12 QuartzCore                     0x18a6fb0e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
13 QuartzCore                     0x18a6fafa8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
14 QuartzCore                     0x18a677c64 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
15 QuartzCore                     0x18a69f0d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
16 QuartzCore                     0x18a69faf0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1873a57dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1873a340c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1873a389c __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1872d2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
21 GraphicsServices               0x188d55198 GSEventRunModal + 180
22 UIKit                          0x18d2ac628 <redacted> + 684
23 UIKit                          0x18d2a7360 UIApplicationMain + 208
24 Dev                            0x100058d14 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x1862b45b8 (Missing)
```

Bellow is the method that I call on `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` that I suspected that could cause this problem but I'm not sure.

```
func checkButtonFML() {
        if logoButton.superview?.subviews.last != logoButton {
            logoButton.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: logoButton)

            self.perform(#selector(self.checkButtonFML), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)
        }
    }
```

This is my method `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 4 , eventsArray.indices.contains(indexPath.row) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: penaltyScoresCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PenaltyScoresTableViewCell
            if indexPath.row % 2 != 0 {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xEDEDED)
            }
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
            let (homeTeamEvent,gameTime,awayTeamEvent) = eventsArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.homeTeamEvent.attributedText = homeTeamEvent
            cell.gameTime.text = gameTime
            cell.awayTeamEvent.attributedText = awayTeamEvent
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell
        } else {
            if eventsArray.count > 5 && indexPath.row == 5, eventsArray.indices.contains(indexPath.row) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: moreEventsCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MoreEventsTableViewCell
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
                cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                return cell
            }
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: gameNewsCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GameNewsTableViewCell
            let eventsArrayCount = eventsArray.count < 5 ? eventsArray.count : 6
            let row = indexPath.row - eventsArrayCount
            if let array = newsArray as [News]? , newsArray?.count > 0 {
                if let date = array[row].date, let title = array[row].title , array.indices.contains(row) {
                    cell.title.text = title
                    cell.date.text = getDateFromNewsString(date)
                }
                if let urlString = array[row].otteluraporttiKuvat , urlString != "" , array.indices.contains(row){
                    let url = URL(string: urlString)
                    cell.poster.image = nil
                    cell.poster.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: { (image, error, imageCacheType, url) in
                        if let height = image?.size.height, let width = image?.size.width {
                            self.imageHeightArray.append(height)
                            self.imageWidthArray.append(width)
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    cell.poster.image = UIImage(named: "default-news-image")
                }
                cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
                cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
            }
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: With all the <redacted>, it's tough to know for sure what's going on, but I would guess it's related to your table view data. Perhaps an index out of range?

Comment: I don't know why crashlytics gave me the log with this many  <redacted>

Comment: Yeah, frustrating to say the least. How many of these do you have, or is it a one-off? Could also be related to CALayer drawing, like a memory buffer overflow or something.

Comment: It doesn't seen to be so frequent,I got 20 out of 1000 sessions.

Comment: Anything specific about the device or screen resolution that's happening? Any correlation between the reports?

Comment: I didn't see any correlation, it happens on all the supported devices and all the supported ios versions (ios 9 - 10).

Comment: Alright, then I stick with my original guess -- something to do with index out of range. Do some testing with flaky network connections, try clearing device cache, installing the app for the first time -- the sort of thing that you wouldn't normally catch in standard testing.

Comment: Ahh, see your update. Try not using #selector unless you have to -- it's not thread safe. Use `dispatch_after` instead. And since this is occurring each time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called, that could run _a lot_ of times.

Comment: You could try posting the code for `...cellForRowAt...` in `CurrentGameViewController`.  Maybe someone would notice something that could go wrong.

Comment: If `indexPath.row` is nil, I could see this crashing (you do `if indexPath.row ==` in a couple places).

Comment: Sidenote: You get `<redacted>` when the SDK tries to read the symbols on the device instead of fetching the symbols from the actual dSYM of that framework. This was introduced by Apple a few years ago to as part of some optimization work.